# MediaPlayer jitters on looping

Tags: android, loops, android-mediaplayer

I want to loop a track using `MediaPlayer`. I have set the `MediaPlayer` object to loop. The problem is the track finishes and goes into next loop, there is a noticeable jitter/lag. How can I avoid that? I currently use the code mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29883923/2606411) link. I use the following code to set up my `MediaPlayer` instance.

```
private void setupMPLesson() {
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    mMPCurrPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMPCurrPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mMPCurrPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + RESOURCES_PACKAGE +
                "/" + R.raw.sweep_up_down_wav));
        mMPCurrPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not find the file:", e);
    }

    // Create the media player instance for the next iteration ...
    createNextMediaPlayer();

}
```

The method `createNextMediaPlayer()` is as follows:

```
private void createNextMediaPlayer() {
        mNextPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mNextPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mNextPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + RESOURCES_PACKAGE +
                    "/" + R.raw.sweep_up_down_wav));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Could not find the file:", e);
        }

        mNextPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mNextPlayer.prepareAsync();

        // setting the completion listener to the mMPCurrPlayer
        mMPCurrPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }
```

Once the `mNextPlayer` is prepared, I do the following:

```
@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mMPCurrPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(mNextPlayer);
    }
```

And on completion of a cloop, I implement the OnCompletionListener as:

```
@Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // Check if the mp completed playing the number of loops required ..
        // If the current loop is smaller than the number of set loops ..

        mCompletedLoops++;

        mp.release();

        // Assign the current mMPCurrPlayer to the created mNextPlayer for looping ..
        mMPCurrPlayer = mNextPlayer;
        // Create the next media player and make it ready for the next iteration ..
        createNextMediaPlayer();

        if (mCompletedLoops < mNumLoops) {
            return;
        }

        // stop the media player ..
        mMPCurrPlayer.pause();
}
```

I also keep the track of the current loop and stop once I have crossed the required number of loops.

Comment: Is this audio only?  or video? Please edit your question and add  your current code that preps, starts, the tracks to be played.

Comment: It is only audio. I think the problem is that the buffer size used by the MediaPlayer is quite big in size and at the end  of one cycle it skips the playback of the last buffer (because it is smaller than size of the buffer size it needs) and that is why I am having this problem.

Comment: For the purpose of looping, I was earlier setting the `MediaPlayer` object to loop by calling `setLooping(true)` on that that object. But, this has noticeable lag at the end while switching into the new cycle. Then I used the solution mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274182/cant-able-to-achieve-gapless-audio-looping-so-far-on-android). This is able to loop seamlessly but I still have the problem with the last buffer, due to which I have an observable glitch with the accompanying visualization.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add your current code that preps, starts, the mediaplayer & the track to be played

Comment: Updated the question with the code, I hope this helps. Btw, I came across another android class known as `AudioTrack` and now I use that for looping. Seem to work quite well for me.