# How to achieve seamless loop with C++ and java in android studio?

Tags: java, android, c++

I just want to achieve gapless loop for audios. I have already tries both answers from stack overflow that we get on googling and also the answer from medium website but none of the seem to work. I was wondering that how the gapless loop is achieved in some of the apps available on play store, mainly the instrumental apps and then I came across C++. But I am not getting any significant method specifically to loop the audio through C++. Also it is important to note that I want only gapless looping and that too where the audio will start instantly without even a second or some milliseconds gap.

**I would also welcome any other method for looping the audio other than C++ if possible.**

Comment: I would guess by sending the audio in a loop, and not adding a gap

Comment: Show us some code. Provide links to the answer you refer to.

Comment: @Jeffrey Links :- [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274182/not-able-to-achieve-gapless-audio-looping-so-far-on-android[link] and also [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274182/not-able-to-achieve-gapless-audio-looping-so-far-on-android/38487142#38487142[link] . For the medium website :- [link]https://medium.com/@viksaaskool/gappless-sound-loop-on-android-1ddeccc563de[link]

Comment: @user253751 Can you please elaborate/explain what you want to say.

Comment: Those answers and solution look fine. You'll need to elaborate on what doesn't work with them.

Comment: @PopcornMovies well what are you doing that creates a gap? Don't do that thing

Comment: @Jeffrey Somehow a minute gap of maybe 1s is noticed after trying those solutions. And because of this gap the app cannot play the audio according to its purpose.

Comment: @User253751 I am doing nothing wrong that lead to the gap as mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: @PopcornMovies I didn't say "wrong". What are you doing that leads to the gap?